# Get elements to fill width screen in LazyHStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `LazyHstack` in a horizontal `scrollview` :

```
struct HorizontalSpotsList: View {
var spots: [Spot]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            LazyHStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                if (!spots.isEmpty){
                    ForEach(spots.prefix(upTo: 3) , id: \.self) { spot in
                        Text("Test").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .fill(Color.white)).border(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).border(Color.red)
        }.frame(width: .infinity, height: 130).border(Color.green)
    }

}
```

[image: example]

**How can i get my lazyHStack elements to fill all the width screen ?**

My `LazyHstack` doesn't seems to fill the width, i tried to apply `.frame(width: .infinity)` or `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` to different combinaisons of my `scrollView` / `LazyHstack` / `Text` element but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Geometry Reader. You would have to apply a height however.

```
GeometryReader { geo in

    ScrollView {

        LazyHStack {

            content

        }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: #)

    }
}
```

Comment: we can use `GeometryReader` to get height of the component. However, it's not suggested to use fixed height here. Adding a `Spacer` should fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Spacer()` in between the `Text` elements.

Comment: Already tried this and didn't work, i managed to do what i want by using  
@Prashant Tukadiya suggestion : Mesuring wifth of scrollview with GeometryReader and assigning the width to my LazyHstack elements